# Pycharm import does not recognize other files in the same module

Tags: import, pycharm

Say, my project structure is as following:

```
project_folder:
  __init__.py
  another_folder:
    __init__.py
    main_file.py
    other_file.py
```

And `main_file.py` contains next code:

```
import other_file as whatever
```

PyCharm (PEP8) highlights this line as an error '`no module named other_file`' and there is no autocomplete on any calls like `whatever.this_should_be_autoc_suggested`. Meanwhile interpreter works perfectly fine.

What can be the cause of this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to mark your project directory as "Sources Root", just right click upon the directory in pycharm, Mark Directory as, Sources Root. that should make the trick for you.